# find Linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Find a linear operator $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ whose spectrum is a given interval $[a,b]$.

How can I find a continuous function whose spectrum is exactly the given interval $[a,b]$, spectrum just states that spectrum lies in disk $\leq \|T\|$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance

Comment: What if you consider $f\mapsto ((b-a)x+a)f$ ?